# How to apply jQuery datatable in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have tried to use jQuery datatable in Entity Framework.

This is my code:

```
  @model IEnumerable< MvcApplication6.Models.Student>

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>



   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" 
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>


     <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
      <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>




</head>
<body>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New","create")
    <table id="tbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
    <thead>

         <tr> 
             <th>
                 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.StudentId)
             </th>

             <th>
                 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.FirstName)
             </th>
              <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Batch)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Class)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.School)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Domicile)
        </th>
              <th>
          Actions
        </th>
         </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.StudentId)</td>

                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.FirstName)</td>
                  <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Batch)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Class)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.School)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Domicile)
        </td>
                <td>
                     @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", new  { id=item.id})|
                     @Html.ActionLink("Details", "details", new  { id=item.id})|
                     @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "delete",new  { id=item.id},new { onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"})
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>

</table>


</body>
</html>



<script type="text/javascript" >
 //jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $("#tbl").DataTable();
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {



    })
</script>
```

jQuery datatable is not applied. I have used razor engine with Entity Framework. I have tried in aspx engine with ado.net, there the jQuery datatable worked properly.

Comment: [Try this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part)

Comment: Try moving the final script section before the closing html tag.

Comment: you are not loading datatables.js

Answer (score 0):

change your datatable links to https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js  and https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css  CDNs.

The "~/" in your link and script are used server side to resolve the URL.  Script and link tags are client side so it will not work.

Comment: I have tried CDN and  scripts at bottom also.now also it is showing an error like as following                                                                                        (index):219 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):219)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)

Comment: did you actually confirm that the included files actually loaded?   Did you move the javascript at the bottom inside the HTML tag? Did you look at the generated document javascript after the page was loaded? A missing quote or something like that can break other includes

Comment: yeah,i have moved scripts  at bottom. you said that generated document javascript after the page was loaded ,where i need to see this?In browser tools everything is showing in network category like css,js